# Notepad++ or python - Compare two lists and change the original changed

Tags: python, regex, list, compare, notepad++

I have this original list.

```
John:password123
Daved:Password123
Steve:Password123
Michael:Password123
```

---

The second list is a random of original list and with changed passwords.

```
Michael:p241d111
John:fcvbfdg122
Steve:pdPo134!
```

What I want is to change the original list with new password but same postion.

For example:

```
John:fcvbfdg122
Daved:Password123
Steve:pdPo134!
Michael:p241d111
```

How to do that in notepad++ or in python!

Comment: What have you tried? Tip: Python is better suited for this than a text-editor

Comment: I think the notepad++ answer is that you delete the text you want to replace and type whatever you want in its place. Unusual question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**test.txt**

```
John:password123
Daved:Password123
Steve:Password123
Michael:Password123
```

**test2.txt**

```
Michael:p241d111
John:fcvbfdg122
Steve:pdPo134!
```

**script.py**

```
lst = {}

with open("test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        split = line.split(":")
        lst[split[0]] = split[1]

lst2 = {}

with open("test2.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        split = line.split(":")
        lst2[split[0]] = split[1]

final_lst = {}

for item in lst:
    final_lst[item] = lst2.get(item, None) or lst[item]

print(final_lst)
```

Here is a simple solution written with Python.

```
~/temp ❯❯❯ python3 test2.py                                                                                                                                                            ⏎
{'Michael': 'p241d111', 'Steve': 'pdPo134!', 'John': 'fcvbfdg122', 'Daved': 'Password123'}
```

Comment: david gomes, what if i want to load them from a text file? two textfiles.

Comment: Then you need to read the lists from a text file into the dictionaries `lst` and `lst2` using Python code to read files. It's very simple :)

Comment: Could have just done that with two files. `with open... etc` doesn't take that long to write. Probably quicker than making those dictionaries.

Comment: David gomes, Kindly can you edit your code with read from textfile function. I am not a python programmer.

Comment: I will not do that. If you are not a programmer, pay a programmer to do this. Stack Overflow is not a website where you can ask people to straight out do things for you.

Comment: No worries, Thank you anyway. Hopefully someone will give a hand.